# Can't get all user locations android

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am having trouble understanding the whole obtain user locations. I followed a tutorial for LocationManager. It gets the last known location from the GPS provider. From what I can tell is some user do not have a last know location and it returns NULL.

I assumed that this code below would if NULL would use the GPS and attempt to obtain a user location. But it does not. How can I force android to retrieve a user location? And not just display my NULL message and not work?

```
setContentView(R.layout.beer_location_list);

        String title = "Nearby Breweries";
        TextView topTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beerLocationTitle);
        topTitle.setText(title);

        //get user location

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null)
        {
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //construct url
            String url = "myURl";

            Log.d("urlTest",url);

            //async task goes here
            new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);
        }

        else{
            //pop toast saying cant get location
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can not get your location at this time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Update:

after looking at some of the responses, why can I not doing something like this to just get the users location each time he opens this activity:

```
  final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

        LocationListener listener = new LocationListener();


        manager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, listener, null);
```

and I override location listener with

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location lastKnownLocation) {
        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
            // whatever needs to be done
        }
    }
```

But I am getting the error: LocationListener is abstract cannot be instantiated  on the line new LocationListener();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request a single update for your location by registering a`LocationListener` and use `requestSingleUpdate` to request an update with the current location. I assume you have the correct permissions listed in your app's manifest. Be aware that you might not receive an update, especially since newer Android versions allow users to disallow location access for an app.

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);

LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location lastKnownLocation) {
            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
               // whatever needs to be done
            }
        }

manager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, listener, null);
```

Comment: I kind of get that I need to requestSingleUpdate which should get the users new location. But I am confused how your code fits into mine?

Comment: Your code starting in the block of `if(location != null)` should go where I wrote `// whatever needs to be done`. Be aware that if you request `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` it may take a while before the GPS has a fix and the listener callback will be invoked.

Comment: thanks! Almost there, now I am getting an abstract error. I added it to my update to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what your additional question is. Are you trying to instantiate an interface instead of an  implementation of an interface?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the last update of the question, it is an abstract class so it can't be instantiated. You need find a concrete class that implements it or implement it yourself.

Take a look at this complete examples on how to use the location API 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

You need to have your activity to implement the LocationListener class and the you can override the functions without having to create a new object.

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
```

Comment: Being more explicit and giving an example (summarising the page you linked, for example) would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

`getLastKnownLocation` only retrieves that historical information if it exists — it does not start the location provider to obtain a lock.

In the event that `getLastKnownLocation` returns `null`, you should use the `requestLocationUpdates` method to get the user's current location.

Also, be aware that the location returned by `getLastKnownLocation` could be very old if no location lock has been acquired lately, so you'll probably want to check the timestamp and assume that it's outdated if its age exceeds a certain threshold.